# How to handle configurable products price rules by size in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, customization, product

I've products (curtains) which my customer can buy after choosing the size in a given unit (it can be metter, or a volume, or anything)

Depending on the units I need to do different computation.

Currently my units are stored as a custom attribute in Magento.

How could I update price depending on the customer choosen "value" with the given units ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try one of these modules:
http://www.magentopricing.com

Most probably "Magento Custom Options Pricing" or "Magento Price Calculator Extension" solves your problem.